# Angular 6 'is not a function' when use this. inside another function

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm having some issues with typescript, I have this code:

```
private loadTeams = function(){
    let token =  sessionStorage.getItem('token');
    if(token !== undefined && token !== null && token !== ''){
      this._userService.getUserByToken(token)      
        .subscribe(user => {
          this._teamService.getTeamsByUser(token, user)
            .subscribe(data => {
              this.teamList = data.data;
            }, error => {

            });
        }, error => {

        });
    } else {
      sessionStorage.removeItem('token');
    }
  }
```

And gives me the error:

> ERROR TypeError: "_this._teamService.getTeamsByUser is not a function"

In other articles, people tell to use arrow function but I think it is already an arrow function?

I have tried to use ***let that = this;*** and then call **that** instead of **this** in the second function but it didn't work.

Another thing that I have seen people doing is to use **.bind(this)** but I don't know where do I do that.

Can someone explain to me why is it happening and how to solve that?

Comment: `loadTeams = function(){` breaks your code. Try `loadTeams() {` instead

Comment: So how should I do the functions? Should I just use loadTeams(){} ?

Comment: using `function` resets `this` to a new scope because of how javascript works. It's messy and nasty, but that's how it works. You can either use methods as @yurzui proposed (which I think is the correct thing to do here), or use arrow functions instead of using the `function` keyword, like this: `private loadTeams = () => {...}`

Comment: I have tried `loadTeams() {...}` and `loadTeams = () => {...}`and the same error keeps showing

Comment: Maybe try using private `loadTeams = function(this){`

Comment: Even if it's a bit random, you can use `switchMap` operator instead than subscribing an observable inside an observable

Comment: Without looking at how you are declaring your service call, it is very hard to tell. Note that none of the ways to declare that call, be it "loadTeams = function()..." or "loadTeams()" or "loadTeams = () => ..." breaks that call, so your issue is probably related to the way the _teamService is initialized/injected.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
private loadTeams = function(){
  // this here refers to the function
}
```

What you should do is this:

```
private loadTeams() {
  // this refers to the instance of the class
}
```

Alternatively, bind this in the constructor like this:

```
constructor(/* inject stuff here */) {
  this.loadTeams = this.loadTeams.bind(this)
}
private loadTeams = function(){
  // this refers to the instance of the class
}
```

However, I'm not convinced this is your problem.

If this was your problem then `this._userService` would be undefined and you would get a `null pointer error` when calling `undefined.getUserByToken(token)`

FYI I've said this 16 times in this post, did you spot this?

Comment: I also am having that issue. service in constructor is undefined when I override an @Input function from a child component. tried that but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

Ok problem fixed. I just used `private loadTeams(){...}` like you told me but I don't know why I had to shutdown angular and do ng serve again to work.

Comment: Do note this is the preferred way to declare a method, but what you had originally or doing a lambda works the exact same way. See my answer somewhere below.

Answer (score 1):

You may have an issue with your _teamService injection or construction. Declaring the loadTeams in different fashions works as long as the service call is not undefined.

So,

`loadTeams() { ...`
or
`loadTeams = function() {...`
or 
`loadTeams = () => { ...`

All do work if things are properly initialized.

I did put together a Typescript Scratchpad to play with this, can't get it to fail with either of those, but then again my fake version of the "_teamsService" is initialized.

See typescript example [Typescript example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20SessionStorage%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20getItem(token)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22fakeToken%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20FakeGetTeamsObservable%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20subscribe(dataCall%2C%20errorCall)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dataCall(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20data%3A%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20FakeGetUserObservable%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20subscribe(dataCall%2C%20errorCall)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dataCall(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20data%3A%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Test%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20runLoadTeams()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.loadTeams()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20teamList%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20_userService%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20getUserByToken%3A%20(token)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert(%22Get%20User%20By%20Token%20reached%22)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20FakeGetUserObservable()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20_teamService%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20getTeamsByUser%3A%20(token%2C%20user)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert(%22Get%20Teams%20By%20User%20reached%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20FakeGetTeamsObservable()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20loadTeams()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20token%20%3D%20fakeSessionStorage.getItem(%27token%27)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(token%20!%3D%3D%20undefined%20%26%26%20token%20!%3D%3D%20null%20%26%26%20token%20!%3D%3D%20%27%27)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._userService.getUserByToken(token)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.subscribe(user%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._teamService.getTeamsByUser(token%2C%20user)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.subscribe(data%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.teamList%20%3D%20data.data%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20error%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20error%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20sessionStorage.removeItem(%27token%27)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20fakeSessionStorage%20%3D%20new%20SessionStorage()%3B%0D%0Alet%20test%20%3D%20new%20Test()%3B%0D%0Atest.runLoadTeams()%3B). You can replace the function definition any of those three ways and things work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Where is this._userService coming from? It probably has not been initialized.

Did you forget to inject it into the constructor?

Comment: Yes it is inserted in the constructor like this `constructor(private _teamService: TeamService, private _userService: UserService) { }`

Comment: Can you please post TeamService Code